# Bundle subdirectory access

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, nsdata

I'm try to implement ability to change interface in my program, something like themes. I'm decide to use bundles, so in my case they looks like this:

- Theme1.bundle
- Theme2.bundle

Every bundle have folders:

- Theme1.bundle

  - graphic

    - pic1.png
    - pic2.png
  - sound

    - sound1.wav
    - sound2.wav

So I can get path to any required picture from bundle with this code:

```
path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.bundle/graphic/%@", selectedBundle, imageName];
```

When I get pictures from bundle there is no problem, path looks like this (I check it using breakpoints):
**Theme1.bundle/graphic/pic1.png** and I create `UIImage`

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
```

Pictures loaded without any problem.

But when I trying to play sound using `AVAudioPlayer`, I get path to sound by same way and path looks like this:
**Theme1.bundle/sound/sound1.wav**, but when I try to create NSData

```
sound = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

it is not initialized.

When I try to keep sounds in main bundle and get it with

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
```

everything is OK, and path looks like this 

**/var/mobile/Applications/E8313E88-CE05-44B2-A80C-B05331D8596F/Myapp.app/sound1.wav**

I cant understand why this works with pictures but not with sound? 

Why I cant get sound from bundle?
Only one thing I can suggest - `imageNamed:` do some work to find right path to file and `dataWithContentsOfFile:` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code instead of

```
sound = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Use

```
NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.bundle/sounds/%@", selectedBundle, soundName]; 
NSString *fullPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
sound = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Explanation:
`ImageNamed` attaches the path of the application to the image name you specify

Comment: Thank you for response, but problem not solved.
When I try to get NSData i have an error:

`"error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldnt be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x1cda6910 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/E8313E88-CE05-44B2-A80C-B05331D8596F/PLWoodTheme.bundle/sound/kSoundTypePaletteShow.wav, NSUnderlyingError=0x1cda6850 "The operation couldnt be completed. No such file or directory"}"`


So with NSHomeDirectory I have not valid path.